# Dataset from_dict() can't load columns with list values

Tags: python, huggingface-datasets

I'm trying to load multi-hot encodings as labels into a Dataset (object in the datasets library) using from_dict(), but the loaded label for each sample has the length of batch_size, instead of the dimension of labels.

A short example:

```
texts = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
multihot_labels= [[0.0, 0.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 1.0]]
dataset = Dataset.from_dict({'text': texts, 'label':multihot_labels})
loader = DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=5)
for batch in loader:
    print(batch['text']
    print(batch['label'])
    break
```

and I got the following output:
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
[tensor([0., 0., 0., 0., 0.], dtype=torch.float64), tensor([0., 1., 1., 1., 0.], dtype=torch.float64), tensor([1., 1., 0., 0., 1.], dtype=torch.float64)]

The output for the text is as expected, but the label is 3 by 5 rather than 5 by 3. I'm very confused by this, and I didn't get any clue after a day's search. Any idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Explicitly declaring columns

```
import torch
from datasets import Dataset, DataLoader

texts = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
multihot_labels = [[0.0, 0.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 1.0]]

label_column = ClassLabel(names=["class_1", "class_2", "class_3"])
dataset = Dataset.from_dict({'text': texts, 'label': multihot_labels}, features={'label': label_column})
loader = DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=5)
for batch in loader:
    print(batch['text'])
    print(batch['label'])
    break
```

Comment: This still gave me 5-dim labels. I also tried using dtype=torch.int, but it didn't help.

Comment: Interesting. Unfortunately, I am not super familiar with the dataset or model here so I'm really just making an educated guess. Have you tried explicitly declaring the dimensions?

Comment: Do you mean in the dataframe or when loading the Dataset? Not sure how to declare that

Comment: Something like the edit I just made. I don't have torch on the machine I am currently on or I could be a little more useful :P

Comment: I had an error running your code, but I found a solution: running dataset.set_format("torch") before the dataloader line somehow solved my issue. Thank you for the help!